# large bitmap size fit in to small android phones

Tags: android

I have a Bitmap with a size of 1024x1024.png and I need to stretch it on different device screens, I tried using this:

```
// given a resource, return a bitmap with a specified maximum height
public static Bitmap maxHeightResourceToBitmap(Context c, int res,
        int maxHeight) {
    Bitmap bmp = imageResourceToBitmap(c, res, maxHeight);


    int width = bmp.getWidth();
    int height = bmp.getHeight();

    int newHeight = maxHeight;
    int newWidth = maxHeight / 2;

    // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;

    // createa matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    // recreate the new Bitmap and return it
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
}

// given a resource, return a bitmap with a specified maximum height
public static Bitmap scaleWithRatio(Context c, int res,
        int max) {
    Bitmap bmp = imageResourceToBitmap(c, res, max);

    int width = bmp.getWidth();
    int height = bmp.getHeight();

    // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
    float scaleHeight = ((float) max) / height;
    float scaleWidth = ((float) max) / width;

    // createa matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    // recreate the new Bitmap and return it

    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

In order to stretch a bitmap on screen I would recommend to keep the bitmap as the original in memory (don't make the bitmap itself bigger in any case).

Then, when you show it on screen, usually with an `ImageView`, you can set the image view `ScaleType`to `FIT_XY` (see [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) for more info). This will stretch the image on screen when drawing it to fill the entire ImageView. Also make sure your ImageView fills the entire screen by setting its LayoutParameters accordingly (fill parent for example).

The only real reason to resize bitmaps in memory is to make them *smaller* to save memory. This is important because Android devices have a limited heap and if you're bitmaps are too big in memory they will fill up your entire heap and you'll run into OutOfMemory errors. See this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) if you're running into memory problems.